# Android Long Polling - Timeout executing service

Tags: android, asynchronous, comet, long-integer, polling

I am trying to implement LongPolling in my Android Application. [Long Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

If the LongPolling needs to long to get a answer my android service crashes.

I tried with Threads and Async. Generally i tried a lot of staff, but i don`t got it.

```
public class PollingService extends Service {

String TAG = "AndroidPolling";
int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 900000;
int mHeartbeat = 10000;
int TIMEOUT_TOLERANCE = 5000;
String mPushURL = "http://192.168.0.115:8080/de.test.jersey.cti/rest/todos/";


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();    
    Log.i( TAG, "RestService Service-Class created");  

}

   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart"); 

    new makepolling().doInBackground("http://192.168.0.115:8080/de.test.jersey.cti/rest/todos/");

}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

---

```
class makepolling extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

String TAG = "AndroidPolling";
int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 900000;
int mHeartbeat = 10000;
int TIMEOUT_TOLERANCE = 5000;
String mPushURL = "http://192.168.0.115:8080/de.test.jersey.cti/rest/todos/";

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String result = null;
    DefaultHttpClient def = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams httpParams = def.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(mPushURL);
    httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "Executing GET(PUSH) request " + httpGet.getRequestLine());

        HttpResponse httpResponse = def.execute(httpGet);
        Log.i(TAG, result);
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(httpResponse.getProtocolVersion()));
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent())); //For testing purposes


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not call doInBackground() explicitly. To start an AsyncTask, you must create an instance of it and call the execute() method on it. [This](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructs-part-3.html) article explains AsyncTask nicely.